# ¿Hay alguna forma de centrar el código en pantalla completa en netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

En sublime text tenía la opción distraction free mode que centraba el código de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Existe una opción así en netbeans? Puedo entrar en pantalla completa pero todo el código se carga hacia la izquierda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Apartir de NetBeans IDE 7.4, distraction free mod, Ctrl-Shift-Enter o Shift+Alt+Enter

Comment: Si, pero no muestra el código centrado que es lo que me interesa.

Comment: Ese es el distraction free mod de NetBeans,  si lo quieres ver centrado porque no lo tabulas y listo?

Comment: Trabajo en un monitor grande y es bastante incomodo estar volteando la cabeza al lado izquierdo siempre que trabajo en pantalla completa. (Muy seguido). Cuando trabajaba en sublime text tenía esta opción y centraba el texto como en la imágen que puse. Era muy cómodo y me gustaría algo así en netbeans.

Comment: Desconozco esa opcion, pero si  entiendo lo que bscas.